# How to quantify the adsorption affinity of gases?

Tags: terminology, adsorption

Is there a term/quantity which shows how 'sticky/adsorptive' a molecule is? I am interested in gas adsorption on steel surfaces in our mass spectrometer and would like to estimate which gases have a higher propensity to adsorb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "[*adsorption enthalpy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adsorption#Adsorption_enthalpy)". However calculating that value will depend on a variety of factors mainly the absorbate and substrate, but it is not that simple. The surface structure of substrates matters and a $[111]$ oriented crystallographic face will have a different adsorption enthalpy with a given absorbate that say a $[001]$ crystallographic face.

I suggest you study this more, namely the [Langmuir adsorption model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langmuir_adsorption_model) and [Brunauer–Emmett–Teller Theory (BET)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BET_theory). Especially since BET is a popular technique to measure adsorption.

Comment: Okay, so there is no simple way of estimating this gas is stickier than that gas provided we talk about the same absorbent,or?

Comment: @Zorg
Critical point is quite useful in that sense. A least you can have some idea form the boiling point of the molecule.